QTabWidget with rounded corners and a unified background for the active tab and content?
I have a QTabWidget with QScrollArea in it. The widgets are placed in Qt Designer.
I want to style it like this:

all external corners of the tab widget are rounded
tabBar has a background the same as the inactive tab
tab content has white background


Edit: I got rid of generic stylesheets, now there are two problems left:

Bottom left corner looks strange. I can see that QScrollArea have correct borders, but something is placed above it.
The background of tab contents is light grey, need to be white.


Edit: I tried to change my code to apply stylesheet to the whole QTabWidget(using ui->tabWidget->setStyleSheet instead of ui->tabWidget->widget(0)->setStyleSheet, but it only became worse, stylesheet doesn't affect tab content at all:

What stylesheet should I use to solve the problems listed above(strange corner and background color) and who should I aplly it to?
mainwindow.cpp:
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->centralwidget->setStyleSheet(       "QWidget#centralwidget {"
                                                "background-color: yellow;}");
    ui->tabWidget->widget(0)->setStyleSheet("QTabWidget::pane {"
                                                "background-color: white;"
                                                "border: 1px solid green;"
                                                "border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;"
                                                "border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;""}"
                                            "QScrollArea {"
                                                "background-color: white;"
                                                "border: 1px solid blue;"
                                                "border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;"
                                                "border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;""}"
                                            "QScrollBar:vertical {"
                                                "border: none;"
                                                "background: transparent;"
                                                "padding: 0px 0px 4px 0px;"
                                                "width: 12px;""}"
                                            "QScrollBar::handle:vertical {"
                                                "border: 1px black;"
                                                "border-radius: 4px;"
                                                "margin: 2px;"
                                                "background: black;"
                                                "height: 240px;""}"
                                            "QScrollBar::add-line:vertical{"
                                                "border: none;"
                                                "background: transparent;"
                                                "subcontrol-position: bottom;"
                                                "subcontrol-origin: margin;""}"
                                            "QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical{"
                                                "border: none;"
                                                "background: transparent;"
                                                "width: 12px;"
                                                "subcontrol-position: top;"
                                                "subcontrol-origin: margin;""}");
    ui->tabWidget->setStyleSheet(
                                     "QTabBar {"
                                        "border: 1px solid grey;"
                                        "border-top-left-radius: 8px;"
                                        "border-top-right-radius: 8px;"
                                        "height: 42px;"
                                        "background-color: grey""}"
                                     "QTabBar::tab {"
                                         "background: grey;"
                                         "border: 1px solid grey;"
                                         "border-top-left-radius: 8px;"
                                         "border-top-right-radius: 8px;"
                                         "font: 16px Manrope Medium ;"
                                         "color: black;"
                                         "height: 42px;"
                                         "padding: 15px;""}"
                                     "QTabBar::tab:selected {"
                                         "background: white;"
                                         "color: blue;"
                                         "border: 1px solid white;"
                                         "border-top-left-radius: 8px;"
                                         "border-top-right-radius: 8px;"
                                         "border-bottom: none;""}");
        ui->tabWidget->tabBar()->setExpanding(true);
        ui->tabWidget->tabBar()->setDocumentMode(true);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

mainwindow.ui
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>100</x>
      <y>50</y>
      <width>621</width>
      <height>471</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="currentIndex">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Tab 1</string>
     </attribute>
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <property name="leftMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="topMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="rightMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="bottomMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
        <property name="widgetResizable">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>0</x>
           <y>-242</y>
           <width>601</width>
           <height>680</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
          <item>
           <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>0</width>
              <height>600</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
            <property name="text">
             <string>PushButton</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
            <property name="text">
             <string>PushButton</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Tab 2</string>
     </attribute>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>


See if these help: Expand tabs in QTabWidget to fill the whole width, How to expand tabs in QTabWidget. I personally would avoid frequent stylesheet changes, so I prefer subclassing.

re: "when documentMode is true, widget's background disappears". QTabWidget::documentMode says (my emphasis): "When this property is set the tab widget frame is not rendered. This mode is useful for showing document-type pages where the page covers most of the tab widget area.". So it appears to be the by-design behavior.

re: "I decided to set tab width programmatically (dividing QTabWidget width by 2). But tabs are bigger than expected and don't fit:". That's because you're setting a static width on a dynamically resizing widget, so the value you're setting on that stylesheet will be whatever size it catches the moment it is calculated. If the tab widget changes its width afterward, it will not look right, whether it's bigger or smaller.

re: "I tried to set ui->tabWidget->widget(0)->setStyleSheet("background-color: white") instead of transparent, but now the corners at the bottom are not rounded". It's just the widget poking outside the tab widget. Set a distinct border colors on the tab widget and the current widget to debug that visually. Just set a border radius on it.

@jdenv The "stylesheet for QScrollArea doesn't apply" part is unclear. You should explain what doesn't work and the expected result, either by adding more details, or by providing an image mock-up of what you want. Generic style sheet properties should also be always avoided for complex widgets and containers, which is what you did for the central widget and the first page of the tabwidget, because those properties will propagate to all their children in unexpected ways (eg, see the ugly scroll bar). Always use selector types.

@musicamante By "stylesheet doesn't apply" I mean that the correct stylesheet for QScrollArea doesn't seem to affect the output. Thanks for the advice about generic stylesheets. I edited my code and it almost works, just one problem left. Edited my question to show it

@jdenv You have to be more precise. You've defined four properties for the QScrollArea, which one doesn't work for you? Also, QTabWidget::pane will never work like that, because you've applied the style sheet to the page content, the tab widget is its parent. At the very least, you should set that rule for the tab widget itself, or any of its parents. In general, setting sparse style sheets is rarely a good idea, because it results in unnecessary fragmentation that causes unwanted results if you're not completely aware about the widget structure.

I found that QScrollArea contains a child QWidget named scrollAreaWidgetContents, so that widget had straight angles and didn't have background. The solution is to hide its borders and make background transparent by adding "QWidget#scrollAreaWidgetContents" section. Next I added 2px border to selected tab to hide QTabBar background under it. The final stylesheet looks like this:
ui->centralwidget->setStyleSheet(               "QWidget#centralwidget {"
                                                    "background-color: yellow;}");
    ui->tabWidget->widget(0)->setStyleSheet(    "QWidget#scrollAreaWidgetContents {"
                                                    "border: none;"
                                                    "background-color: transparent;}"
                                                "QScrollArea {"
                                                    "background-color: white;"
                                                    "border: 1px solid white;"
                                                    "border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;"
                                                    "border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;""}"
                                                "QScrollBar:vertical {"
                                                    "border: none;"
                                                    "background: transparent;"
                                                    "padding: 0px 0px 4px 0px;"
                                                    "width: 12px;""}"
                                                "QScrollBar::handle:vertical {"
                                                    "border: 1px black;"
                                                    "border-radius: 4px;"
                                                    "margin: 2px;"
                                                    "background: black;"
                                                    "height: 240px;""}"
                                                "QScrollBar::add-line:vertical{"
                                                    "border: none;"
                                                    "background: transparent;"
                                                    "subcontrol-position: bottom;"
                                                    "subcontrol-origin: margin;""}"
                                                "QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical{"
                                                    "border: none;"
                                                    "background: transparent;"
                                                    "width: 12px;"
                                                    "subcontrol-position: top;"
                                                    "subcontrol-origin: margin;""}");
        ui->tabWidget->setStyleSheet(
                                        "QTabBar {"
                                            "border: 1px solid grey;"
                                            "border-top-left-radius: 8px;"
                                            "border-top-right-radius: 8px;"
                                            "height: 42px;"
                                            "background-color: grey""}"
                                         "QTabBar::tab {"
                                             "background: grey;"
                                             "border: 1px solid grey;"
                                             "border-top-left-radius: 8px;"
                                             "border-top-right-radius: 8px;"
                                             "font: 16px Manrope Medium ;"
                                             "color: black;"
                                             "height: 42px;"
                                             "padding: 15px;""}"
                                         "QTabBar::tab:selected {"
                                             "background: white;"
                                             "color: blue;"
                                             "border: 2px solid white;"
                                             "border-top-left-radius: 8px;"
                                             "border-top-right-radius: 8px;"
                                             "border-bottom: none;""}");
        ui->tabWidget->tabBar()->setExpanding(true);
        ui->tabWidget->tabBar()->setDocumentMode(true);


